# Image duplicates in mysql c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm working onto a Web project asp.net and mysql 
I want to the users to upload the images but might some of users has same images names, might I know how to save the images avoiding duplicatation. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Append the name with a GUID or the User's ID or something, or replace the name entirely with a GUID.

Answer (score 0):

rename the image with generated guid:

```
string getNewFileName() => Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your support, is there a way to rename it with the Id of the user

Comment: you can put the ID at the first of the name, or as a folder. Usually date will be the folder name of the user uploaded files.